# How to sort and separate an array in a special way

Tags: python, pseudocode

I have a table with three columns and it has this structure:

```
    Date  |  Hour  |  Status  |
    ---------------------------
    23/05 |  12:00 |  Stop    |
    23/05 |  12:20 |  Stop    |
    23/05 |  12:40 |  Running |

    23/05 |  13:00 |  Running |
    23/05 |  13:06 |  Stop    |
    23/05 |  13:15 |  Running |
    23/05 |  13:20 |  Running |
    23/05 |  13:40 |  Running |  

    23/05 |  14:00 |  Running |
    23/05 |  14:01 |  Other   |
    23/05 |  14:20 |  Other   |
    23/05 |  14:40 |  Other   |
    23/05 |  15:00 |  Other   |
    ...
```

I would like to sandwich all the status in one hour and end up with a table like so:

```
Date  |  Hour  |  Status  |
---------------------------
23/05 |  12:00 |  Stop    |
23/05 |  13:00 |  Running |
23/05 |  14:00 |  Other   |
```

The criteria would be by taking the average of times that a status has spent the most time on.

The problem I have is that for each hour we could have either 3 rows or we could have several, there is no way of knowing so we have to calculate it...
How could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try the split() function, I am not sure what the equivalent is in python, but in JavaScript you could do something like:

```
Data = Data.split(" | ")
```